# Get all selected items in an xaml listbox?

Tags: xaml, powershell, listbox, selected

Could someone tell me how I can save all selected items in a xaml listbox in Powershell? I can one selected item, but not all selected items when the listbox selectionmode is set to "extended"?

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxRelations" Margin="1,53,0,174" FontSize="11" SelectionMode="Extended" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="417"/>
```

After

```
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

$WMFStruct.SelectedHosts = $ListBoxRelations.SelectedItem
```

The above line only gets the first selected item in the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting a single item with the call to `$ListBoxRelations.SelectedItem`. You need to get the `$ListBoxRelations.SelectedItems`.

Then you can loop over the items.